# Get ADInterstitialAd to load more often on iPad: possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, iad

I'm testing my iAd on my iPad, and I can't seem to get my `ADInterstitialAd` to load very often.

It does run occasionally but most of the time the first method below is called

```
- (void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError*)error{
    NSLog(@"Ad Failed");
    //[self cycleInterstitial];
}
```

However when I try to reload it upon failing.(**see below method**) It just fails over and over. I dont see why apple would let it just fail in a testing environment. I have read that the fill rate can be low, but it seems really low just for a test iPad app.

```
- (void)cycleInterstitial{
    // Clean up the old interstitial...
    interstitial.delegate = nil;
    [interstitial release];
    // and create a new interstitial. We set the delegate so that we can be notified of when 
    interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
    interstitial.delegate = self;
}
```

Can anyone please advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. Apple is solely responsible for the fill rate of iAds, including interstitial iAds for iPad. As developers and users, we do not have any direct control over this.